# Cordova - InAppBrowser is not getting closed in iOS with executeScript used

Tags: javascript, cordova, inappbrowser

I am trying to close inAppBrowser instance in cordova app for iOS inside executeScript callback function.

```
var ref=null;
ref = window.open(encodeURI(g3SSOUrl), '_blank', 'location=no');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', activityAfterLoadStart);
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event){
 ref.executeScript(
     { code: "document.body.innerHTML" },
     function( values ) {
         values=values+"";
         if(values.lastIndexOf("objectsMap")!=-1){
             var dataStr=values.split(">")[1].split("<")[0];
             console.log("values ----> "+dataStr);
             activityAfterIDPLoginSuccess(JSON.parse(dataStr));                 
             setTimeout(function(){
                   ref.close();
               },2000);

         }
     }
 );
});
```

But inAppBrowser instance is not getting closed. it works if I close inAppBrowser in normal callback functions of inAppBrowser.

Does anybody has idea about this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting error for issue of cordova plugin, 
I updated dialogs plugin now its working.
Due to that error it was not executing setTimeout command as well.